# Pygame – Creating multiple lines with the same function while keeping individual functionality

Tags: python, dictionary, pygame

I'm creating a game for my cs class right now and the model is Tron. Basically, I have my two players going at all times and they can either turn left or right (at 90° angles) whilst creating lines behind them. I want to create a function that will draw those lines given the last position of the player. However, what I can't figure out is how to *create new lines* when the player turns while keeping the old one functioning as it should (I will get to what this means in a bit). Also, since I will be calling this "draw lines" function from the same variable every time, will I be able to detect a collision between the player and any given line by calling that one variable, even though the lines are all technically different? Is this an optmical situation for a dictionary?

So far me and my partner have tried elongating one rect, creating a list (although I don't have much experience in this area, so maybe I just messed it up royally) and otherwise literally creating mulitple variables...

[My code](https://marinacademy-my.sharepoint.com/personal/gdavidson_ma_org/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?folderid=12749fdfcbf57469c97c64d7436139cb5&authkey=ATeJ0cTmrzIIiB9m5wIXJBA&e=adbfe33c3cc94ba6a124e6b8e7a1d06c) (if you decide to check out the code and play the game just keep in mind the next button from the instructions screen is broken for some reason and requires spam clicking).

Comment: @skrx sure thing.

Comment: Please don't post links to your code and just add it to your question instead. Also, try to reduce it to a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: BTW: instead of `rect[0], rect[1]` you can use `rect.x, rect.y`, instead of `rect.bottomleft[0], rect.bottomleft[1]` you can use `rect.left, rect.bottom` - see more in official documentation for [Rect()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)

Comment: use list to keep all lines, and then you can use `for` loop to works with all lines.

Comment: @skrx oh. sorry. Not very learned in stack exchange etiquette yet. Ill work on a more concise example right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this: Use `pygame.Rect`s for the lines because they have useful collision detection methods. When the player moves, you just increase the size of the current rect and when the direction is changed, you can append this rect to a list of rects and create a new one. For the collision detection you would iterate over the `rects` list and use the player rect's `.colliderect` method.

Here's a complete solution:

```
import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((800, 600))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()

    background_color = (30, 30, 30)
    blue = pg.Color('dodgerblue1')
    lightblue = pg.Color('cadetblue3')
    sienna = pg.Color('sienna1')
    player_color = lightblue

    player = pg.Rect(400, 300, 10, 10)
    vel = Vector2(3, 0)
    current_rect = pg.Rect(400, 300, 0, 10)
    rects = [current_rect]

    done = False
    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_d:
                    vel.x = 3
                    vel.y = 0
                    # A new rect with 0 width.
                    current_rect = pg.Rect(player.topleft, (0, 10))
                elif event.key == pg.K_a:
                    vel.x = -3
                    vel.y = 0
                    current_rect = pg.Rect(player.topright, (0, 10))
                elif event.key == pg.K_w:
                    vel.y = -3
                    vel.x = 0
                    current_rect = pg.Rect(player.bottomleft, (10, 0))
                elif event.key == pg.K_s:
                    vel.y = 3
                    vel.x = 0
                    current_rect = pg.Rect(player.topleft, (10, 0))
                if event.key in (pg.K_d, pg.K_a, pg.K_w, pg.K_s):
                    # Append the new current rect.
                    rects.append(current_rect)

        # Update the position of the player.
        player[0] += vel.x
        player[1] += vel.y

        # Need to adjust the rect position if we're moving up or left.
        if vel.x < 0:
            current_rect.x += vel.x
        elif vel.y < 0:
            current_rect.y += vel.y
        # Increase the size of the current rect.
        # abs is needed to avoid negative width & height.
        current_rect.w += abs(vel.x)
        current_rect.h += abs(vel.y)

        player_color = lightblue
        # Collision detection with the rects.
        for line_rect in rects:
            if player.colliderect(line_rect):
                player_color = sienna
                break

        screen.fill(background_color)
        # Draw all rects in the list.
        for line_rect in rects:
            pg.draw.rect(screen, blue, line_rect)
        # Draw the player rect.
        pg.draw.rect(screen, player_color, player)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

Comment: this is a free-range kind of "get help if you're stuck" type kind of project. Thanks for the help though! I got it working using some of your techniques. And yea, as you were saying, checking for collision has proved very hard. Mainly because the turtle always detects the rect it just created behind it! Anyway, thanks for your help

Comment: You're welcome! I'd like to see your code. You could post it as an answer here if you want.

Comment: I would but... its about 728 lines currently and (like I said) its missing the collision and powerups components currently. You can still access it through the link I suppose. Let me update it real quick...

Comment: Oh, that's too much code for SO. Actually, I was only interested in the collision detection part (I'd like to figure that out as well). You could maybe upload your project to GitHub and show it to me later when it's more complete.

Comment: yea sure! I'll put it on Github. Never actually used that before, but I'll keep you posted. I think you def deserve some credit for helping solve one of the most oddly challenging issues i've come across in my project aha

Comment: I've added a complete solution.